# Word 2010 Content Control Corruption on Reload

Tags: templates, ms-word, openxml, word-contentcontrol

We're experiencing a problem building templates in Word 2010 that feature Content Controls. These templates are used in conjunction with a custom system we have inherited that uses them to build reports.

These templates feature nested Content Controls thus:

```
<CONDITION>
    <IF>{xpath}</IF>
    <THEN>
        {rich text}
    </THEN>
</CONDITION>
```

The IF is used to determine whether a condition specified via an {xpath} is true or false. If it is true the content contained within the THEN control is then used.

The odd thing is there doesn't seem to be a problem building the templates. When they are saved they work fine in the custom system. However, when they are later re-opened in Word 2010, the {rich text} that was suppose to appear in the THEN Content Control is replaced with the {xpath} from the IF Content Control thus:

```
<CONDITION>
    <IF>{xpath}</IF>
    <THEN>
        {xpath}
    </THEN>
</CONDITION>
```

As the templates work with the system it seems like this corruption occurs at the point where they are re-loaded into Word 2010. As such, it seems like the first time we'll get to know about this corruption is when someone reloads the template to make further alterations, days, weeks or many months later. By which time we may have forgotten what should be there and lost an awful lot of work.

Can anyone explain why this corruption might be happening?

I've looked on the internet for an answer but found nothing.

Comment: Hi Stephen, it might be useful to show a relevant abstract of the open xml before and after the corruption

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there is a mistake in your code causing malformed XML. When opened, Word tries to interpret the malformed XML and as a result you are ending up with undesired results.